# updating array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

what is my mistake in this code.. whenever i try to update its saying, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0=T , 1=H , 2=R , 3=M, banned='0' WHERE `cid`='6'' at line 1

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
foreach($name as $field => $value){
  $list[] = $field.'='."".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."";
}
$field = implode(', ',$list);

mysql_query("UPDATE subcours SET ".$field.", banned='{$_POST['status']}' WHERE `cid`='{$eid}' ") OR DIE (mysql_error());
```

Comment: You'll probably want to think about using _[prepared statements](http://us1.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)_ in the near future...

Comment: what's the value of $field? Did you check it?

Comment: "Identifiers may begin with a digit but unless quoted may not consist solely of digits. " http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

Comment: the name of the column is 'name' $field is number.. how can i change $field with column name?

Answer (score 2):

First, `$field` in the foreach loop appeared to be a number (`$name` is a numeric indexed array), which could not be the column name.

Second, you missed the single quote.

```
$list[] = $field."='".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
```

Third, consider using ***[PDO](http://php.net/manual/book.pdo.php)***.